# sed command with /w parameter in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a shell script where I am using a sed command with /w flag to create an output file.  When I try to use that file within the script, I get File not found, but after the script exits, it is created in the directory.

Can I use the file created inside the script? What do I need to do for that to work?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
fileQual=Test_load

dataFile=$fileQual.dat
corruptDataFile=$fileQual.err

cp "${dataFile}" "${dataFile}".cpy

LANG=C sed -n '/[\x00-\x08\x80-\xFF\x0B-\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21-\x2B\x2F\x3A-\x40\x5B-\x60\x7B\x7D-\x7F]/w '${corruptDataFile}' ' "${dataFile}".cpy
echo "file corruptDataFile = ${corruptDataFile}"
ls ${corruptDataFile}

function checkNattach()
{
    local fname="$1"
    local atch
    if [ -f "$1" ];then
        atch="-a ${fname} "
        echo "${fname} exists"
    else
        echo "${fname} not found"
    fi
    #resFun=atch
    # echo " in function checkNattach  atch  $atch "
    # echo " in function checkNattach  resFun   $resFun "
    echo $atch
}

TIME=`date +%F-%H%M%S`                   # time stamp to the backup file
FILENAME="Test-$TIME.zip"        # defining the format of the file name while backing up

echo $FILENAME
zipincl=""
zipincl="${zipincl} $(checkNattach ${corruptDataFile})"
echo "**********zipincl  ${zipincl}  ${corruptDataFile}  "

zip -9 $FILENAME $corruptDataFile $dataFile
```

And the output is

```
file corruptDataFile = Test_load.err

ls: Test_load.err: No such file or directory


Test-2016-06-29-204904.zip

**********zipincl   Test_load.err not found  Test_load.err  
+ zip -9 Test-2016-06-29-204904.zip Test_load.err Test_load.dat
        zip warning: name not matched: Test_load.err
```

After the script finishes, when I look in the directory, the file actually is there.  Is there a way I can use it in the zip command?

Comment: What do you wish to accomplish with `\x00-\x08\x80..`?

Comment: Basically, removing the lines in the file that contain those characters

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you isolate your problem in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also, what operating system are you running? `/usr/bin/bash` seems like an odd place, and the OS will affect the flavour of other tools that you're running, like `sed`. Oh, and as a general rule, always quote variables in bash. `dataFile="$fileQual.dat"`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion about using quotes around variables. I do do that, just didn't in the abbreviated example I was doing.   This is the verifiable example from a very big script.  I am on RHEL 5.x.  I did get a resolution from @pradip's observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LANG=C sed -n '/[\x00-\x08\x80-\xFF\x0B-\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21-\x2B\x2F\x3A-\x40\x5B-\x60\x7B\x7D-\x7F]/w '${corruptDataFile}' ' "${dataFile}".cpy
```

Remove space after `'${corruptDataFile}'` from above line. It's creating filename with space at end.

Comment: It seems to be the cause.  I will perform some more tests and report here.